# Getting some wrong string in arabic language only when using socket.io in android

Tags: kotlin, socket.io, arabic

I want to show `لديك طلب جديد لخدمة إطار ${requestId}` string but getting "J*E H69 916 ,/J/ EF B(D 'DH14) D7D(C B547730" string from socket.io

using socket.io version 0.8.3.

Comment: You should definitely move to a stable socket.io version 0.x is WAY too old... It might also fix your issues...

Comment: @Khez I also tried with the latest versions like 2.0.0 but still facing same issue.

Comment: Have you reached to any solution @OBLIGOMEDIVOYAGE ? i'm suffering from this issue as well, socket.io client 0.6.3 and server v2.3.0

Comment: @mohdule Not yet

Comment: Ok so i got the to the bottom of it, i upgraded both my client and server to the latest version now everything works fine, there seems to be some sort of issue with Arabic text in older io.engines.

Comment: i faced this issue with clustering the server with pm2, after upgrading everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with the client.
Upgrade both your client and server to the latest `socket.io` versions.

You see the problem is not from the server but rather the old client of yours (i believe the old engine has issues with Arabic) , proof of this is that if you listened in the middle through a web client Arabic text will be received correctly, but on the android client it will be deformed.

But you see upgrading the client to the latest version will require you to update your server as well, check the compatibility section on the link below.

https://socketio.github.io/socket.io-client-java/installation.html